# Sublime find in folder hotkey

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

When I right click on a folder in the sublime sidebar, it has the find in folder option in the context menu.

Is there  a way I can map this find in folder command to a hotkey?

So whatever folder I have highlighted in the sidebar, I can just hit that hotkey to bring up find in folder function.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I find your answer in Sublime Text 2's GitHub Page, take a look:

https://gist.github.com/eteanga/1736542

Comment: That is not the answer. Find in folder is a different command than find in files, which is why they have different names.